# Is "Playing festivals" correct?

Tags: meaning

I heard some people say that. I want to know if "I love playing festivals" is correct or needs "at"... Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This use of 'play' with a particular venue as its direct object has been common among theatre people and musicians for at least a century.

> We kept on our route and played every town in Arkansas that received mail as often as twice a week. —[*The Green Book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=j24hAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA880&dq=%22played+every+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zWULVJ7BBIP9yQTCrYBI&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22played%20every%20town%22&f=false), (1910)

Comment: Moreover, this usage goes beyond actors and musicians. For example, police officers could say, "I love working festivals," and vendors could say the same thing. In all cases, an _at_ could be added, but it's completely unnecessary.